# NULL values in multivalue parameter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables, ssrs-2008

This stored procedure beneath fills up my `Projectphase` parameter. So as you can see, the user first has to select `@PurchaseOrder`, which will then fill up the Projectphase Parameter.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_GetProjectPhase] 
     @PurchaseOrder INT
AS
    SELECT       
        pp.ProjectPhaseID, pp.Phase  
    FROM        
        ProjectPhase pp
    WHERE       
        @PurchaseOrder = pp.PurchaseOrderId
```

Now when the user selects a `PurchaseOrder` that indeed has `Projectphases`, everything goes well. The issue situates itself in the purchaseorders that don't have a `ProjectPhase`.

The query that is used for my dataset shown on the report  has the following line in the WHERE clause. It's a multivalue parameter cause the user needs to be able to select multiple Projectphases.

```
WHERE 
    reg.ProjectPhaseId IN (SELECT Value 
                           FROM fnLocal_CmnParseList(@Phase,','))
```

I've tried UNIONS with NULL, NULL. I've tried stuff with ISNULL but I can't seem to be getting the query to execute when `@ProjectPhase` is NULL.

Some help would be greatly appreciated cause I've been cracking my head on this for too long now. Thanks

Comment: if @Phase is null then it makes sense that the dataset returns empty.

Comment: yes I know, but how can I make it not be empty. Is it just a small adjustment in my where clause? Projectphase needs to be able to have multiple values or to have an NULL value.

Comment: Perhaps I'm having a moment of enhanced density, but it isn't clear whether you want to be able to retrieve rows where `ProjectPhaseId` is actually NULL. Something like `WHERE reg.ProjectPhaseId IN (SELECT Value FROM fnLocal_CmnParseList(@Phase,',')) or ( @Phase is NULL and reg.ProjectPhaseId is NULL )`. Perhaps you could clarify with some sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the answer:

```
[dbo].[USP_GetProjectPhase] @PurchaseOrder INT
AS

SELECT      -1 AS 'ProjectPhaseID'
            ,'No Filter' AS 'Phase'
UNION
SELECT       pp.ProjectPhaseID
            ,pp.Phase  

FROM        ProjectPhase pp
WHERE       @PurchaseOrder = pp.PurchaseOrderId
```

In my query I changed the WHERE clause to:

```
WHERE (reg.ProjectPhaseId IN (SELECT Value FROM fnLocal_CmnParseList(@Phase,',')) OR @Phase = '-1')
```

Comment: so @phase is not derived from phase but from ProjectPhaseID??